# how does the np.index_exp[] work in the 3D voxel / volumetric plot with rgb colors example

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am reading the example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_rgb.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-voxels-rgb-py about creating a 3d sphere.
But I don't understand how the indexing works in the example. Can any one help me to understand. Thanks

```
> def midpoints(x):
> sl = ()
> for i in range(x.ndim):
>>    x = (x[sl + np.index_exp[:-1]] + x[sl + np.index_exp[1:]])
>>    sl += np.index_exp[:]
>>    print(np.index_exp[:-1])
>>    print(x[np.index_exp[:-1]])
```

````
I know the "index_exp[:-1]" returns (slice(None,None,-1),) and "x[index_exp[:-1]]" will give result like this:
[[[0 0 0],
  [0 0 0],
  [0 0 0]],
[[1 1 1],
  [1 1 1],
  [1 1 1]]]

But I don't understand how the ```x[index_exp[:-1]]``` in the for loop only shows:
[[[1 1 1],
  [1 1 1],
  [1 1 1]]]
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, `x`, is one of the (17,17,17) arrays produced by

```
In [208]: r, g, b = np.indices((17, 17, 17)) / 16.0
     ...: rc = midpoints(r)
     ...: gc = midpoints(g)
     ...: bc = midpoints(b)
```

`indices` is like `meshgrid` and `mgrid`, creating grid arrays.

I haven't used `np.index_exp`, but I see it's the same as `np.s_`, except it always returns a tuple

```
In [225]: x = r.copy()
In [226]: ()+np.index_exp[:-1]    # so this tuple can joined with sl
Out[226]: (slice(None, -1, None),)
In [227]: x[()+np.index_exp[:-1]].shape
Out[227]: (16, 17, 17)
In [228]: x[:-1].shape
Out[228]: (16, 17, 17)
```

so

```
x = (x[sl + np.index_exp[:-1]] + x[sl + np.index_exp[1:]])/2.0
```

for the initial `sl`, this is

```
x = (x[:-1] + x[1:])/2.0
```

`x[1:]-x[:-1]` is widely used to take the difference between adjacent elements, `np.diff`.  Here it just acts on the first dimension (of 3).  So this is just the mean of adjacent points. Note both `x[:-1]` and `x[1:]` are (16,17,17) arrays.

The next bit just adds a `[:]` slice to `sl`:

```
In [230]: sl += np.index_exp[:]
In [231]: sl
Out[231]: (slice(None, None, None),)
In [232]: sl + np.index_exp[:-1]
Out[232]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, -1, None))
```

So this is doing

```
 x[:, :-1]     # which should be a (17,16,17) array
```

and the next iteration `x[:,:, :-1]    # (17,17,16)`

This `r` varies only in the first dimension, so can compare its values with the `midpoints` with:

```
In [249]: r1 = midpoints(r)
In [250]: r[:5,0,0]
Out[250]: array([0.    , 0.0625, 0.125 , 0.1875, 0.25  ])
In [251]: r1[:4,0,0]
Out[251]: array([0.03125, 0.09375, 0.15625, 0.21875])
```

So the use `index_exp` just allows them to write the `(x[:-1]+x[1:])/2` averaging in a general way that applies to all 3 dimensions the `r`, `g`.`b` arraus/

Comment: Thanks. that helps. I have another question. I am wondering what the purpose of calculating the mean point between adjacent points, since the final array is just one layer less. Is it to make sure that final sphere is off the edge.